# Is it possible to change color in codeblocks?

Tags: codeblocks

Is it possible to change codeblocks color to dark mode or something that is not white.
I don't mean the code background, but the IDE itself.
[This part of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxmkW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The CodeBlocks GUI is built on the wxWidgets libraries which currently do not implement the use of themes (dark mode).